# Yad dialog image to run a script?

Tags: yad

How to make the image in yad dialog box clickable to run a bash script? I have tried this line...

`yad --title="WeatherIcon" --image=forecaNOW.png --dclick-action="bash -c 'weatherBOX.sh'" --no-buttons`

Answer (score 0):

After searching for an answer, **--dclick-action** is for rows, not images. There is another option for an image adding it to a button, of any size.

`yad --title="WeatherIcon" --button='!forecaNOW.png!Name:bash -c "./weatherBOX.sh"'`

**Screenshot:** (forecaNOW.png size 92x175)

[image]